# Ajax call on checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, checkbox

I am having a two checkboxes.Now on click of one of the checkbox I want to make an ajax call to a jsp page.That jsp page is to show a table that contains datat being fetched from database.

Now,The problem is say i have two checkboxes like :

```
<div class="search-inputs">

        <input class="searchName" type="text" placeholder="Search Here.."></input>

        <input class="searchType1" type="checkbox" name="emailNotification"><label class="searchtype1label">Email Notification</label></input>
        <input class="searchType2" type="checkbox" name="SharingNotification"><label class="searchtype2label">File Sharing Notification</label></input>


        <input class="searchDateFrom" type="text" placeholder="Search From"></input>
        <input class="searchDateTo" type="text" placeholder="Search To"></input>
        <input class="Datesubmit" type="button" value="Search"></input>
        <div id="container"></div>
```

How to do it ?Please help

```
My Script part : 

$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.search-select').on('change', function(){
            $('.search-inputs').children().hide();
            var classn =$(this).find(":selected").val();
            //alert(classn);
            if(classn=='searchName')
                {
                    //alert("searchname");
                    $('.'+"searchName").show();
                }
                else if(classn=='searchType')
                {
                    //alert("searchType");
                    $('.'+"searchType1").show();
                    $('.'+"searchtype1label").show();
                    $('.'+"searchType2").show();
                    $('.'+"searchtype2label").show();
                }
                else if(classn=='searchDate'){
                    //alert("searchType");
                    $('.'+"searchDateFrom").show();
                    $('.'+"searchDateTo").show();
                    $('.'+"Datesubmit").show();
                }

            });

            $('#emailNotification').on('change',function() {
            //var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if(this.checked){

            //alert("in");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchOnType.jsp",
                data: {mydata: "emailNotification"},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('it worked');
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert('it completed');
                }
            });

            }
      });

      });
```

But how to show the table on the same page ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I edited .Please check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to change your html slightly with this--

give same class name to both check boxes.

```
<input class="searchType" type="checkbox" name="emailNotification" id="emailNotification"><label class="searchtype1label">Email Notification</label></input>
 <input class="searchType" type="checkbox" name="SharingNotification" id="SharingNotification"><label class="searchtype2label">File Sharing Notification</label></input>
```

Now slightly change in jquery part--

```
$('.searchType').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
       if(this.checked){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'searchOnType.jsp',
                data: $(this).attr('id'), //--> send id of checked checkbox on other page
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('it worked');
                    alert(data);
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert('it completed');
                }
            });

            }
      });
```

Comment: why u copied the code from other answer?And by the way i had added that source

Comment: It worked .But why the html from that page is not being displayed here.For testing i just take a heading on that page like <h1>"HELLO"</h1>

Comment: is there any error showing in console..? or are you sure ajax is getting right url path.?

Comment: Yeah i am sure as on success i printed the data in alert and it displayed all  html  on other page.It is something like this : <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: their is no error on the console as the other page is just created and just contains a hello world msg

Comment: Will you put content of searchOnType.jsp page..?

Comment: @shahsank thanx it worked actually i was not  closing above divison.Now how to decide which of the two text boxes is checked and make decision depending on one is selected,none is selected or two are selected

Comment: In the above code as am just taking emailNotification I have one more checkbox.How to decide it which are selected and send it as parameter to the ajax call

Comment: @shahsank Last question before accepting what if i want to select both checkboxes?

Comment: It depends on your requirement if you want to process ajax function on individual checkbox or to process ajax function once for both checkboxes.

Comment: @shahsank it depends.It can be single or both

Comment: the problem is that if i check first checkbox then it make ajax call and print the table required.Now when i click on second then it will substitute the contents being shown by first one.Am i wrong?

Comment: then you need to add a button and click on it after checking desired checkbox and call ajax function on its click.

Comment: Cant i move the output of both checkboxes on different divisons?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. different division means..?

Comment: Like here we are moving our html response on container div tag of html.But we can keep two different divisons.One for each checkbox.Am i wrong?

Comment: Your mean ajax function should call on both checkboxes and responsed data should not overide to each other..? means You want both responsed data in your html container div. Am I right.?

Comment: then you simply append data in container HTML div on success of ajax call using  $('#container').append(data); in place of $('#container').html(data);   this will append new responsed data with previously appended data besides replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `change` event for this like below:

**Html:**

```
<input class="searchType1" type="checkbox" name="emailNotification"><label class="searchtype1label">Email Notification</label></input>
<input class="searchType2" type="checkbox" name="SharingNotification"><label class="searchtype2label">File Sharing Notification</label></input>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#emailNotification').on('change',function() {

            if(this.checked){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchOnType.jsp",
                data: {mydata:"emailNotification"},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('it worked');
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert('it completed');
                }
            });

            }
      });
```

Comment: How the table will be printed on same page which is making the call?

Comment: see edit you need to make a container div and load response html in it

Comment: where is the problem coming is ajax call sent?

Comment: No call is not being sent.I tried to print an alert but no alert being printed

Comment: see the edit, put url in quotes and check data attribute change

Comment: @EhsanSjjad Still no success.Do u think this is correct : $('#emailNotification').on('change',function() ?I edited my html part in question.Please check it once

Comment: @shashank i had added it.

Comment: Is it going in the if of checked?