# Opening an HTML page with pre checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to open my HTML page with checked checkboxes if they were checked on the page prior to opening the current one. My current code is as follows:

```
  {% if job.activism %}
  checkbox??????       
  {% endif %}
 <br><input type="checkbox" name="activism" value="Yes">Activism & advocacy
```

My backend is django and my front end is HTML.
Thanks

Comment: if u want to open an HTML page on checkbox then you can call ajax on the checkbox check.you can see this answer for better refence:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269413/ajax-call-on-checking-a-checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the checkboxes are shown by default, and checked only if your condition returns true, then try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="activism" value="Yes" {% if job.activism %}checked{% endif %}>Activism & advocacy
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "checked" attribute, for example:

```
<br><input type="checkbox" name="activism" value="Yes" checked>Activism & advocacy
```

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```